# Car submit form with images

Tags: mysql, sql, forms, gallery, image-uploading

I'm making a car dealer website, don't have much experience with coding though. 
I have a form with multiple selects and text areas and i also need to add 3-5 images to this form to display later with the car info. How should my database look like.
carID carMake carModel etc. but how to i save these 3-5 images to this database? should i make separate inputs like image1 image2 etc upload them and then save url's to database?. I stumbled upon an "blueimp jQuery File Upload" it seems nice etc, but i don't understand how to save the multiple file array to the database with the other car info. Any ideas? Or examples how to properly perform this?

Comment: why make a table for each image1, image2, image3.. when you can make a table images, and save carId - imageURL ( because i think you would preffer to save the url, not the image itself since the images are way bigger). you should first post what you've done already

Comment: It's a kinda big form many options and text areas:) and yeah you're right i just want to save the url's (forgot to mention in the original post). I have the car id as an auto increment in the database, don't know how to atach the car id to the images or smth.. i'm new to coding and i cant find a decent answer on google so i'm trying to learn something here :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Between `CarTbl` and `CarImagesTbl` is a one-to-many relationship. The primary key of `CarTbl` will be foreign key in `CarImagesTbl`, this way you will be able to identify to what car does belong each image. [image]

After you insert the car into database, you get its primary key, and looping trough the array of imagesURL, you insert the values in the CarImagesTbl. To get the images for one specific car, you do a join between the tables

```
Select URL,CarID
From CarImagesTbl ci, carTbl c
Where c.carId = ci.carId_FK 
and c.carId = wantedCarId
```